# AVX support problem

Tags: python3, tensorflow

When I `import tensorflow` in `python` shell it gives error:

> `The TensorFlow library was compiled to use AVX instructions, but these aren't available on your machine. Aborted`

Whereas i have **intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 520 @ 2.40GHz × 4**
please help..

Comment: What OS & release you're using is more important than whatever CPU you're using.  Is it Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop?, or something else, and what release? etc.

Comment: Intel i5-520M does not have AVX instructions [in silicon](https://valid.x86.fr/lsx8fd). You have to find some [software hack](https://www.google.com/search?q=tensorflow+without+avx+ubuntu&oq=tensorflow+without+avx) or buy/try newer laptop with [AVX enabled CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/search/featurefilter.html?productType=873&1_Filter-InstructionSetExtensions=3531).